# asp.net: How do I submit a form with javascript dissabled?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, form-submit

I am writing a website on which any user using any browser might disable Javascript.
In that situation, I still need to submit a form.  How do I do that?

Here is what I've done so far without success:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DefaultNoJavaScript.aspx.cs" Inherits="DefaultNoJavaScript" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
</head>
<body id="DefaultNoJavaScriptContent" runat="server">
    <form id="LoginForm" runat="server" method="get" action='<%=ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx")%>'>
        <table ID="LoginTableNoJavaScript" Style="border-collapse: collapse; width:345px;">
            <tr id="TableRowFirst" >
                <td id="LoginBox">
                    <input type="text" id="UserName" style="width:170px;" value="Your browser disabled Java-" />
                </td>
                <td id="BlankBox" >
                    <input type="text" id="Label1" value=" " style="width:2px; display:none;"/>
                </td>
                <td id="PasswordBox">
                    <input type="submit" name='PasswordX' id="PasswordX" value="script!  Enable it to use site." style="width:165px;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is a solution that I found that does as I wish:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DefaultNoJavaScript.aspx.cs" Inherits="DefaultNoJavaScript" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
</head>
<body id="DefaultNoJavaScriptContent" runat="server">
    <form id="LoginForm" method="post" action="/default.aspx" >
        <table ID="LoginTableNoJavaScript" Style="border-collapse: collapse; width:345px;">
            <tr id="TableRowFirst" >
                <td id="LoginBox">
                    <input type="text" id="UserName" style="width:170px;" value="Your browser disabled Java-" />
                </td>
                <td id="BlankBox" >
                    <input type="text" id="Label1" value=" " style="width:2px; display:none;"/>
                </td>
                <td id="PasswordBox">
                    <input type="submit" name='PasswordX' id="PasswordX" value="script!  Enable it to use site." style="width:165px;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When do you need to submit the form? When the user does something?

Comment: `<form> <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </form>` -> click the button

Comment: You don't need JavaScript to submit a form.

Comment: Here is a solution that I found that works:

Answer (score 6):

How about the ye olde submit button?

```
    <form action="someUrl" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Some Input"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am writing a username/password screen.  I need a hidden submit input to postback when the user hits enter on the password textbox.  The method that I use with Javascript enabled won't work with it disabled.

Comment: Sorry, m.casey.  I'm still not there with a solution.  I've added code above to show what I've found so far.

Comment: The above will submit to the specified action with the specified method without or without JavaScript being enabled. If you've additional requirements, then please edit your question to reflect them along with the results of your current efforts so that we might assist you.

Answer (score 0):

In far off cases you can open a c#, c++, etc program and have a submit form there after you disable javascript. Or you can create a program to disable javascript using a language like c#, java, or c++, or some other language.
Note: this may not be that helpful. Just to give you ideas if you didn't have them already.

Comment: It would also help me come up with a strait forward approach to this problem if you explained why you need a submit form.

Comment: Hi genius.  I've added code above to explain my issue more fully.  Basically I want a username/password screen that redirects when Javascript is disabled.

Comment: Sorry it is impossible to make that work without javascript. Maybe you could try other security techniques or if you know another language then I could help you make a form in a window. From there you could disable javascript and still run your program.

Comment: Also may I know why you want to disable JS?

Comment: Hi genius.  I don't want javascript disabled.  I am working around issues that occur when the user disables javascript.  This became an issue that my QA team determined that I had to work through.

Comment: So your saying, before even opening your site the user disables JS?